# CloudFlare claiming my website is malicious.

Tags: php, curl, web, cloudflare

So I have been trying to get data from a website API theTVDB.com and everything works fine on my localhost. But When I try and get the XML file from my hosted website CloudFlare is claiming my web server is infected with a virus and prompts for captcha. Only problem is, its a curl request so I cant input the captcha and it essentially just returns nothing. Any idea how to pause a php script so I can enter the captcha or to stop it from happening? The specific URL I used in testing was http://thetvdb.com/api//GetSeries.php?seriesname=New%20Girl which works fine on any computer I test it on except my server (little nimvbus hosting) Below is my curl code. (the response I am printing is how I know captcha is being requested)

```
    protected static function fetchData($url) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch ,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$data = substr( $response, $headerSize );
curl_close($ch);
if($httpCode != 200) {
return false;
}
return $data;
}
```

Comment: We take for granted you've already investigated the virus claims and just want a workaround until they update their database, huh?

Comment: I contacted my host right away since it is a shared server. They assured me it was fine and linked me a Sucuri SiteCheck of my website with 0 issues found.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already actually contacted our support team? They'd be who you need to speak with directly.  You'll need to white list (mark as trusted) the IP you're making this connection from to ensure you don't receive the challenge security page when trying to access the site.

p.s. I do work for CloudFlare.